# Leafler R Shiny : Add a new marker in map on click event

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I am using leaflet library in R Shiny. I want to add a new marker on the map with a mouse click. I am able to fetch latitude and longitude using `input$mapid_click` option. But I am not able to update the map in shiny app with a new marker.

Answer (score 2):

You can add them using the `leafletProxy` function.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput('map')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({leaflet()%>%addTiles()})

  observeEvent(input$map_click, {
    click = input$map_click
    leafletProxy('map')%>%addMarkers(lng = click$lng, lat = click$lat)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since shiny 1.6.0, `observeEvent(event,expression)` has been deprecated in favour of `observe(expression) %>% bindEvent(event)`. So [the answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55688660/7372346) by @Wilmar-van-Ommeren would become:

```r
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput('map')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({leaflet()%>%addTiles()})

  observe({
    click = input$map_click
    leafletProxy('map')%>%addMarkers(lng = click$lng, lat = click$lat)
  }) %>%
  bindEvent(input$map_click)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```